Origin of Planar Diagram codes (PD codes) of link diagrams
My question is who and where Planar Diagram codes of link diagrams were first introduced.
I read here, that Planar Diagram codes are used in Mathematica, but I am not sure whether the author also meant to imply that they were first developed there (since PD codes are now also used in various other mathemtical software programs like SnapPy, Sage or Regina).
I have this question because I am writing about PD codes and want to accurately give credit to this combinatorial description of link diagrams. DT-codes for example, were introduced Dowker and Thistlethwaite in a paper called "Classification of knot projections".
Thank you for any help.
